# Output of the number of iterations processed by each thread

Tags: c++, openmp

I have written code for parallel matrix processing using OpenMP that should output information about the number of iterations for each thread.

However, the output contains information for only one thread. I just started learning OpenMP and I haven't been able to figure out what the problem is.

```
int main() {

    int n;
    cout << "Enter matrix range: ";
    cin >> n;

    int** A = new int* [n];
    int** B = new int* [n];
    int* C = new int[n];  
    int* D = new int[n];  

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A[i] = new int[n];
        B[i] = new int[n];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            B[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    int thread_num;
    int it_num;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 4) num_threads(4)
    {
        auto start_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int it_num = 0;
            int minA = A[i][0];
            it_num++;
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (A[i][j] < minA) {
                    minA = A[i][j];
                    ++it_num;
                }
                
            }
            printf("thread %d processed %d iterations\n", omp_get_thread_num(), it_num);
            C[i] = minA; 
        }
        
        auto end_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();
        cout << "Time taken for schedule(static, 4): " << duration << " microseconds" << endl;
    }
}
```

Can you help me understand why the output only contains information for one thread, and how to fix it?

Comment: *I have code that processes a matrix in parallel* -- Is this actually relevant to the problem you are seeing?  Can you simply duplicate the issue by seeing if any output, regardless of where or how it was produced, can be outputted?  For example, a simple `Hello World` printed 4 times?

Comment: The code you have posted won't compile. Please post a code that actually compiles and that we can test. Also, post the output produced by your code, and explain precisely what is wrong according to you.

Comment: Is it too much too ask to get some feedback from you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions.

1. create an array of private counters, one per thread
2. Decouple your `omp parallel for` into a `omp parallel` and `omp for`
3. Between those two lines, let each thread compute its number
4. In each iteration each thread updates its counter.

> ```
> int itcount[nthreads];
> # pragma omp parallel
> {
>     int thread_num = omp_get_thread_num();
> #   pragma omp for schedule(guided)
>     for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
>       itcount[thread_num]++;
>       // rest of the loop
> ```

Second solution: use `threadprivate` data.